# Empty IP address after run container in host mode

Tags: java, docker

I want to create docker container with **host mode**, using java library

https://github.com/spotify/docker-client

In my container exist my application which after run should open port `20202` from container to next using. So my code to do that is

```
Map<String, List<PortBinding>> portBindings = Maps.newHashMap();
portBindings.put("20202", Lists.newArrayList(PortBinding.of("localhost", "20202")));
        HostConfig hostConfig = HostConfig.builder()
        .networkMode("host")
        .portBindings(portBindings)
        .build();
ContainerConfig config = ContainerConfig.builder()
        .hostConfig(hostConfig)
        .image("myImage")
        .exposedPorts("20202")
        .cmd("myProg", "arg1", "arg2"))
        .build();
DefaultDockerClient.fromEnv().build();
client.pull(config.image());
ContainerCreation creation = client.createContainer(config);
client.startContainer(creation.id());
ContainerInfo info = client.inspectContainer(creation.id());
```

I see in log how my image is pulling, from local registry, but when my main program try run command in created container I get below exception

> org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: URI does not specify a valid host name: http://:20202

After when my program run this container I checked manual from command line if container exist, and if port is open localy on `127.0.0.1:20202` and it is ok,

- container exist and is running (I see them after `docker ps`)
- Port is open and listening I check using `netstat -altp` --->
  `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:20202  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN      23839/myProg`
- I can use my program just use `127.0.0.1:20202`

I saw that problem is when in my main program try get information about host from `ContainerInfo` using below method

```
ContainerInfo info = client.inspectContainer(creation.id());
String host = info.networkSettings().ipAddress(); // host is empty
```

So question is, how put to `ContainerInfo` information about `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` when I set **host mode** in `HostConfig` ? 
Why this is not happend automatic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port bindings are ignored when you have host mode, because your code is responsible for choosing the port and binding to it. Docker is just patching your through to the host network. So whether you pass port mapping or not, it will not used in host mode

Also when you run a container is NetworkMode there is no IP assigned to container as such. You need to use the host IP

```
$ docker run -d --network host alpine sleep 900
804006d7f917637ee615d877558da7fae5b01a03af713c773098d0ef563d06c2

$ docker inspect 804006d7f917637ee615d877558da7fae5b01a03af713c773098d0ef563d06c2 | grep IPA
  "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
  "IPAddress": "",
  "IPAMConfig": null,
  "IPAddress": "",
```

As you can see from above, then container never gets an ip in host mode

Comment: So only way is set manualy in my code `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`? eg using `if(config.networkMode().equal("host"){ host = "127.0.0.1";}` ?

Comment: Yeah that is your call how you intimate your code that is running with host mode in the container. I usually prefer to configure these things through environment variables